# multiple aggregate root creation in one single transcation in CQRS

Tags: cqrs

I would like to know how multiple aggregate root are created in CQRS.

Example: I have a handset aggregate root and Simcard aggregate root. The id 
from these aggregate should be part of subscription aggregate root .

i need to create a Subscription aggregate based on SimCard and an Handset.SimCard and Handset aggregate do not exist in the system . they are created when Subscription is created .
When Subscription  is deleted  SimCard and Handset is not deleted.
 Business reason: user might insert different SimCard  into the same Handset  or the handset supports dual SimCards.

business rule : 
 Phone number should be unique. 
 Handset serialNumber should be unique. 
 One subscription is associated with one handset 
 One handset is associated with 1 or more phone number.

```
Class Handset { 
  String serialNumber 
 Handset(UUID id,serialNumber){ 
    super(id); 
    this.serialNumber=serialNumber; 
} 
} 

Class SimCard{ 
  String phoneNumber 
  SimCard(UUID id, String phoneNumber){ 
     super(id); 
        this. phoneNumber= phoneNumber;
  } 
 } 

Class Subscription { 
     UUID id 
     UUID deviceid 
      UUID simCardid 

    Subscription (UUID id, UUID deviceid, UUID simCardid){ 
             Super(id); 
             This. Deviceid= deviceid; 
             This. simCardid= simCardid; 
     } 
     }
```

- Hide quoted text -
- Show quoted text

Comment: What command are you trying to model? the AddSubsriptionCommand ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Saga for this.
See:

1. [Saga Persistence and Event-Driven Architectures](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/04/20/saga-persistence-and-event-driven-architectures/)
2. [A Messaging Saga](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/04/08/A-Messaging-Saga.aspx)
3. [Rhino Service Bus: Saga and State](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/01/16/rhino-service-bus-saga-and-state.aspx)

Also take a look at [Don’t Create Aggregate Roots](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/)